# Temporarily install a package to RAM

Tags: unix

When you use `apt-get`, `yum`, `pkg_add` or MacPorts to install a package, the package is written to the hard disk. How to install them temporarily to RAM instead so that they will be removed when you reboot?

Comment: Maybe RAM disk + UnionFS?

Comment: It realy seems you are trying to takle a problem the wrong way. So what is your actual problem? Why do you need to temporarily "install" software into RAM?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that with the package manager.
What you could do, is grab the deb / rpm file, unpackage it to a ram disk, and then symlink all the files to the right locations, but that would be a nightmare.

Why do you want to do that ?